# preg_match_all - get part between pattern and string

Tags: preg-match

In this example i have large string with many defined elements in it
[part of example string here](http://creativeit.lv/strings.txt).
In this example i get matches from example file (Starting from **first(~32)** tilde, to **~120 3**), which sloud be correct in my regex, but i need update regex so it get first closest match in reverse from **~120 3**, so the result be:

> PRIEDE EGLE BERZS LAPU KOKI

```
<?php

        $regex = '/~[1-9](.*?)\~120 3/s';
        preg_match($regex, $str, $matches);

        echo '<pre>';
        print_r($matches);
        exit();
    ?>
```

So the question is: 
How should i set direction to get part of string in "reverse"? If i match ~120 3, then i get all results from ~120 3 in reverse until i match tilde symbol+number - ~[1-9]?

Attached image of my currect regex result and marked few elements:
 * Green - element which i know and in my imagination - will start search in reverse.
 * Grey - the correct result.
 * Red - firest match what was found in reverse from **~120 3**

[image]

Thanks for recommendations in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the question is:

> How should i set direction to get part of string in "reverse"? If i match `~120 3`, then i get all results from `~120 3` in reverse until i match tilde symbol+number - `~[1-9]`?

IT is not possible to change Boost regex matching direction within the input, *however*, you may use lookaheads to restrict the text matched.

Acc. to the requirements, you need

```
~[1-9]([^~]*(?:~(?![1-9])[^~]*)*)~120 3
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/vdnaz9/2).

**Details**:

- `~[1-9]` - your initial delimiter
- `([^~]*(?:~(?![1-9])[^~]*)*)` - Capturing group 1 matching:

  - `[^~]*` - any 0+ chars other than tilde
  - `(?:~(?![1-9])[^~]*)*` - 0+ sequences of:

    - `~(?![1-9])` - a tilde that is not followed with a digit from `1` to `9`
    - `[^~]*` - any 0+ chars other than tilde
- `~120 3` - end delimiter

However, it won't capture what you need since it will include some digits and space at the start. Maybe your starting delimiter should be `~[\d\s]+` and the lookahead then should be `(?![\d\s]+)`. See [another demo](https://regex101.com/r/vdnaz9/4).